# Usando React, Typescript e NodeJS. Envio de formulário para cadastro de usuário em JSON. Só sei usar FormData. Como passar os elementos como JSON?

Tags: node.js, react, typescript

**Frontend**

```
import React, { useState, FormEvent } from 'react';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../../components/header/header'
import './register.css'
import Image from '../../assets/images/register.svg'
import api from '../../services/api';

export default function CreateUser() {

    const history = useHistory();

    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [secondPassword, setSecondPassword] = useState('');

    async function handleSubmit(event: FormEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const data = new FormData();

        data.append('name', name);
        data.append('email', email);
        data.append('password', password);
        data.append('secondPassword', secondPassword);

        await api.post('register', data);

        alert('Cadastro realizado com sucesso')

        history.push('/')

    }

    return (
        <div id="register-landing">
            <Header />
            <div className="content-wrapper">
                <div className="img-div">
                    <img className="img" src={Image} alt="Register" />
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="form" method="post" >
                    <div className="content">
                        <div className="text">
                            <h1>Cadastro</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div className="input-block">
                            <label htmlFor="name">Nome</label>
                            <input
                                id="name"
                                value={name}
                                type="text"
                                onChange={event => setName(event.target.value)}
                                placeholder="Insira seu nome..."
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-block">
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                            <input
                                id="email"
                                value={email}
                                type="text"
                                onChange={event => setEmail(event.target.value)}
                                placeholder="Insira seu email..."
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-password-area">
                            <div className="input-password">
                                <label htmlFor="password">Senha</label>
                                <input
                                    id="password"
                                    type="password"
                                    value={password}
                                    onChange={event => setPassword(event.target.value)}
                                />
                            </div>

                            <div className="input-password">
                                <label htmlFor="secondPassword">Confirmar Senha</label>
                                <input
                                    id="secondPassword"
                                    type="password"
                                    value={secondPassword}
                                    onChange={event => setSecondPassword(event.target.value)}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="buttons">
                            <Link to="/" className="cancel-button">
                                Cancelar
                        </Link>
                            <button type="submit" className="register-button">
                                Cadastrar
                        </button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

**UserController**

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm'
import User from '../models/user'
import * as Yup from 'yup';

class UserController {
    async protected(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const getUser = getRepository(User)
        return res.json(getUser)
    }
    async store(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const repository = getRepository(User)
        const {
            name,
            email,
            password,
            secondPassword,
            phone,
            about,
            joinDate
        } = req.body

        const userExists = await repository.findOne({ where: { email } })

        if (userExists) {
            return res.sendStatus(409)
        }

        const data = {
            name,
            email,
            password,
            secondPassword,
            phone,
            about,
            joinDate
        }

        const schema = Yup.object().shape({
            name: Yup.string().required('Nome obrigatório'),
            email: Yup.string().required('Email obrigatório'),
            password: Yup.string().required('Senha obrigatória'),
            secondPassword: Yup.string().required('Senha de confirmação obrigatória'),
            phone: Yup.string(),
            about: Yup.string(),
            joinDate: Yup.string()
        })

        await schema.validate(data, { 
            abortEarly: false })

        const user = repository.create(data)
        await repository.save(user)

        return res.status(201).json(user);
    }
}

export default new UserController();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa Andre!

Para enviar um json, você deve colocar o Content-type do Header como 'application/json' e o body você envia em formato de uma string.

No seu exemplo, `data` será um simples objeto, e no seu método api.post você pode passar para o body com `JSON.stringify(data)`, assim o objeto estará no formato certo para requisição.

Ficaria dessa forma:

```
async function handleSubmit(event: FormEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
       name,
       email,
       password,
       secondPassword
    };

    await api.post('register', data).then((response) => {
       alert('Cadastro realizado com sucesso')   
       history.push('/')
    }).catch((err)=>{
       // handle exception error
    })

}
```

[Stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
[Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, fiquei alguns dias quebrando a cabeça

Comment: Se resolveu o problema, marque como solução para ajudar os próximos devs ( e me ajudar também haha! )

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro no servidor **express** você deve passar essa configuração para ele trabalhar com o formato **json**:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

No seu **controller** você pode acessar esse dado no formato **json** assim:

```
app.post('/exemplo', (request, response) => {
  const { atributoJson, outroAtributo } = request.body
  
  // seu código

  return response.status(201).json(objetoJson)
})
```

No seu **frotend react**, caso esteja usando **Axios** como lib para http, você precisa configurar o formato de conteúdo da requisição como **json**, dessa forma:

```
const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://...',
  timeout: 15000,
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
});
```

ou

```
axios.post('https://example.com', formularioJson, { headers: {"application/json"}})
```

Com essa configuração é só passar um objeto json como conteúdo da requisição que vai dar tudo certo

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, resolvi de outro modo

Comment: Se resolveu de outra maneira poste aqui para ajudar outras pessoas ou marque esta resposta como solução caso ela também resolva seu problema. Abraço